# How to get more than 1 question to populate the same field/column in the Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am looking for some way to get the submitted answers to 2 or more questions to populate in the same column in the response spreadsheet, but on the next row.

e.g. When gathering data from franchisees who own more than 1 store in the franchise:

1. What is the name of your Store?
2. Where is your store Located?
3. If applicable, What is the name of your 2nd Store?
4. Where is your store Located?
5. If applicable, What is the name of your 3rd Store?
6. Where is your store Located?

I want Questions 1; 3; 5 to populate in column one under the heading: "Name of Store"
I want Questions 2; 4; 6 to populate in column two under the heading: "Location of Store"

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, stick around as it might take a while for an answer. Welcome on Web Applications !!

Answer (score 1):

The absolute simplest approach is to just put StoreNumber onto the form, and ask people to complete the form once for each store that they own.

This is the easiest way to deal with the fact that they may own different numbers, eg one may have two, another four.